# How to deal with spaces and quotes in the command line

Tags: command-line, networking, bash, wine

I have used [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1188099) for preventing programs use the Internet connection on Ubuntu/Linux.

However I still can't complete the last step as shown:

```
$ ni wine C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
$ ni "wine C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe"
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `wine C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit    Reader\FoxitReader.exe'
$ ni wine "C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe"
Usage: wine PROGRAM [ARGUMENTS...]   Run the specified program
       wine --help                   Display this help and exit
       wine --version                Output version information and exit
$ ni wine FoxitReader.exe
Usage: wine PROGRAM [ARGUMENTS...]   Run the specified program
       wine --help                   Display this help and exit
       wine --version                Output version information and exit
```

Answer (score 2):

Syntax errors means that the shell has trouble interpreting your commands. This is a result of the fact that the shell splits words based on spaces when it parses a command line. Without quotes, each individual part of the argument (such as`C:\Program`) is treated as a separate argument by itself. You can use quotes to prevent the word splitting:

```
ni wine "C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe"
```

This passes two arguments to the `ni` command: `wine` and the full Windows path for FoxitReader.

When you tried placing the opening double quote before `wine`, the shell treated the whole lot of `wine C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe` as one argument for the `ni` command.

If you want to avoid similar issues in the future, I’d recommend checking Greg’s wiki for an in-depth explanation on [how the shell deals with spaces](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting). You may not understand it all but you should still learn why, when and how to avoid word splitting problems.

Answer (score 1):

What Anthony said is true, you can use "" to say the whole path is a string, but maybe this is worth a consideration, as with this method yo ucan use  to complete your paths: There are many special characters in a unix terminal, including spaces,*,newlines and other. You can ignore them by typing a "\" before them. So if a folder is named "My test", u can either use `cd "My test"`, or `cd My\ test`, which you can  complete. But in wine you'll probably have to use the Michaelsoft Binbows convention "".(no offense, just Microsoft jokes :D )

"Protip :D" Sometimes you may want for some reason write a "\" character. To write it, you have to protect it, so you put another "\" before it.
So if you want to write "Protected character \" you actually do `echo Protected character \\`. Note that echo takes string arguments so you don't have to protect the space.

Hope it helps :)